# Mybatis not handling ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, jdbc, mybatis, hsqldb

I have columns in a database table of type `DATE` which I'd like mybatis to convert to `java.time.ZonedDateTime` but it seems that the built in [ZonedDateTimeHandler](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/ZonedDateTimeTypeHandler.java) is not working. I get the following exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column 'UPDATED_DATE' from result set.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:87)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createUsingConstructor(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:711)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createByConstructorSignature(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:694)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:658)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:631)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:355)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:329)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:302)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:195)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:325)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:89)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:151)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getObject(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.ZonedDateTimeTypeHandler.getNullableResult(ZonedDateTimeTypeHandler.java:38)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.ZonedDateTimeTypeHandler.getNullableResult(ZonedDateTimeTypeHandler.java:28)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:85)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: JDBC does not define support for ZonedDateTime. Support is therefor non-standard, and will vary by driver.

Comment: Exactly, this is why mybatis should not assume that it is supported. See my solution below to use setTimestamp(...) and getTimestamp(...) in a custom TypeHandler

Comment: Consider using `LocalDateTime` (if the column is a `java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP`) or `OffsetDateTime` (if the column is `java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE`). Using `java.sql.Timestamp.from(Instant)` can produce inconsistent results given how `java.sql.Timestamp` is handled in "the default JVM timezone".

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, Timestamp and Date classes don't understand the concept of a timezone. They are both just a representation of milliseconds since epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

Comment: That is *technically* what `java.sql.Timestamp` is. But that is not how it is specified to be used. Given a value of `2022-06-24 17:30:00` in a `TIMESTAMP` (without time zone) column, that value needs to be interpreted in the JVM default timezone (as that is specified by JDBC). So if your JVM is in UTC, it will have an epoch millis of 1656091800000, is your timezone Europe/Berlin, then it is 1656084600000, etc.

Comment: And the other way around this also applies: storing a millisecond value of 1656091800000 (i.e. `new Timestamp(1656091800000L)`) when your default JVM time zone is UTC, produces a `TIMESTAMP` value of `2022-06-24 17:30:00`, but storing the same millisecond value in Europe/Berlin produces `2022-06-24 19:30:00`.

Comment: Consider the "fun" when you have applications in different JVM timezones (or the same application where the default time zone is changed at some point during the lifetime) accessing the same data and you expect the resulting milliseconds to be stable. This is why JDBC 4.2 introduced use of `java.time.LocalDateTime` for `TIMESTAMP`, and `java.time.OffsetDateTime` for `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE`.

Comment: I can assure you that I am well versed in timezone issues. As you can see I'm wanting to use ZonedDateTime in my application code (ultimately to pass dates to and from a client as json) and it's only mybatis that needs to deal with Timestamp under the hood. Since epoch is UTC, both Date and Timestamp are milliseconds since a point in time in UTC.  Date and Timestamp have no concept of timezone, it's only when we write them to a string (eg json or show on a UI) or convert them to a ZonedDateTime that the concept of a timezone appears

Comment: My point is that value that is stored for a `java.sql.Timestamp` with a certain epoch millisecond value depends on the current default JVM time zone, and thus can exhibit unexpected behaviour if you run from machines with different time zones, or if the machine hosting your JVM changes config of its time zone.

Comment: Regardless of where the JVM is running (and it's default timezone) clients will be passing in ZonedDateTime (either in the client timezone or UTC) and my application will respond with ZonedDateTime (in UTC). So the server can be running anywhere in the world and the behavior will be consistent. If I was passing around LocalDateTime  your comments are obviously true

Comment: This small [test](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1478#issuecomment-513266102) should demonstrate the fundamental issue of `java.sql.Timestamp`. `java.sql.Timestamp` (or `java.util.Date`) internally relies on the default time zone and it simply cannot hold 'a value that does not exist in the default time zone'. So, as long as the conversion involves `java.sql.Timestamp`, there can be a scenario that produces an unexpected value.

Comment: Thanks, that test doesn't even involve a jdbc driver or database. Seems there's a bug in `java.sql.Timestamp`. I'll have to investigate further and perhaps switch to `OffsetDateTime` if both my drivers support it (hsqldb for unit testing, oracle in production)

Comment: @lance-java Among the drivers I [tested](https://gist.github.com/harawata/2d14ece14581089180da4708df0e074f#file-zoneddatetimetest-java), only Oracle supported `ZonedDateTime`. `OffsetDateTime` is widely [supported](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1368#issuecomment-428922657) including HSQLDB and Oracle. It usually requires particular data type on the DB side, though.

Comment: And thanks Mark Rotteveel for your persistence, my assumption that Timestamp treats millis the same as `java.util.Date` was obviously incorrect

Answer (score 0):

HSQL does not have native support for `ZonedDateTime` but it does have support for `OffsetDateTime` for columns of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (see [HSQL datetime types](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_datetime_types)). HSQL was throwing exception with the built-in [OffsetDateTimeTypeHandler](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/OffsetDateTimeTypeHandler.java) so I had to write a custom [TypeHandler](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/TypeHandler.java)

```java
public class HsqlOffsetDateTimeTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<OffsetDateTime> {
    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, OffsetDateTime parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        ps.setObject(i, parameter);
    }

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return (OffsetDateTime) rs.getObject(columnName);
    }

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return (OffsetDateTime) rs.getObject(columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return (OffsetDateTime) cs.getObject(columnIndex);
    }
}
```

I registered this via

```java
    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
        Environment environment = new Environment("default", transactionFactory, dataSource);
        org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration configuration = new org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration(environment);
        TypeHandlerRegistry typeHandlerRegistry = configuration.getTypeHandlerRegistry();
        typeHandlerRegistry.register(OffsetDateTime.class, new HsqlOffsetDateTimeTypeHandler());
        configuration.addMapper(MyMapper.class);
        ...
        return new DefaultSqlSessionFactory(configuration);
    }
```

I also had to declare my columns as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` instead of `DATE`

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    PK            NUMBER(12),
    NAME          VARCHAR2(255),
    CREATED_DATE  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    UPDATED_DATE  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    DELETED_DATE  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
);
```

Prior to registering my custom TypeHandler I was getting the following exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column 'UPDATED_DATE' from result set.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:87)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createParameterizedResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:678)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getObject(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.OffsetDateTimeTypeHandler.getNullableResult(OffsetDateTimeTypeHandler.java:38)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.OffsetDateTimeTypeHandler.getNullableResult(OffsetDateTimeTypeHandler.java:28)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:85)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 86 more
```